# Jsfiddle not showing map

Tags: html, maps, jsfiddle

I am trying to get this jsfiddle to work but it is not bringing up the map like it does at the website I've copied below. It does bring up the search box but that's not really working either. I'm new at this so I'm probably putting the information in the wrong place. I put in the script like I did the last time I got one of these to work.

Thanks for helping.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveD.html

https://jsfiddle.net/vibajajo64/shou156m/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
//  width: 80%;
}

#side_bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }

  #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
</style>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: SearchBox</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places,geometry"></script>
    <script>
var map = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var destMarkers = [];
var service = null;
var noAutoComplete = true;
var initialService = null;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)});
    var startLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7902778, -73.9597222); // Manhattan, NY
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center:startLoc,
        radius:10*1609.34, // 10 miles
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeColor: "black",
    strokeOpacity: 0.9,
        fillColor: "red",
        fillOpacity: 0.15,
    clickable: false,
        map: map
     });

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  var places = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  gmarkers = [];

  document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML ="<h5>found "+results.length+" places</h5>";
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var place = results[i];
    places.push(place);
    createMarker(results[i]);
  }

  map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
  // if (markers.length == 1) map.setZoom(17);
  var destArray = [];
  destMarkers = [];

  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++){
    if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(startLoc, gmarkers[i].getPosition()) < 10 * 1609.34) { // 1609.34 meters/mile
       destArray.push(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
       destMarkers.push(gmarkers[i]);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML ="found "+destArray.length+" places within 10 miles<br>";
  var DistanceMatrixService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  DistanceMatrixService.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [startLoc],
      destinations: destArray,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false,
    }, function (response, status) {
       var distancefield = distancefield;
         if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
           var origins = response.originAddresses;
           var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
           var results = response.rows[0].elements;
           var htmlString = "<table border='1'>";
       var within10min = 0;
           for (var r = 0; r < results.length; r++) {
               var element = results[r];
               var distancetext = element.distance.text;
               var durationtext = element.duration.text;
               var to = destinations[r];
        if (element.duration.value <= 10 * 60) {
                 htmlString += "<tr><td>"+response.originAddresses[0]+"</td><td>" +
                 "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(destMarkers["+r+"],\"click\");'>"+to+"</a></td><td>"+distancetext+"</td><td>"+durationtext+"</td></tr>";
         within10min++;
               }
            }//end for r
           htmlString += "</table>"; 
           document.getElementById('info').innerHTML +="found "+within10min+" within 10 minute drive<br>";

           document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += htmlString; 
         }//end if status=ok
       })//end callback

  }
}

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);
      // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
      // looking something like  "?marker=3"

      // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
      var query = location.search.substring(1);

      // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
      var pairs = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
        // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
        switch(argname) {
         case "q":
      var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1);
          break;
         default:
      var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();
          break;
        }

        // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
        if (argname == "q") { 
           noAutoComplete = true;
           document.getElementById('target').value = unescape(value);
  var request = {
    bounds: circle.getBounds(), // new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(1.1548,103.571), new google.maps.LatLng(1.567,104.12)),

    query: unescape(value)
  };
        }
        if (argname == "lat") {lat = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "lng") {lng = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "zoom") {
      zoom = parseInt(value);
      myGeoXml3Zoom = false;
    }
        if (argname == "type") {
// from the v3 documentation 8/24/2010
// HYBRID This map type displays a transparent layer of major streets on satellite images. 
// ROADMAP This map type displays a normal street map. 
// SATELLITE This map type displays satellite images. 
// TERRAIN This map type displays maps with physical features such as terrain and vegetation. 
          if (value == "m") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;}
          if (value == "k") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;}
          if (value == "h") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;}
          if (value == "t") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;}

        }
      }
  document.getElementById('target').value = "Starbucks";
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.65, -73.95), // Brooklyn, NY
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false
  });
  circle.setMap(map);
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  initialService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(evt) {
    startLoc = evt.latLng;
    circle.setCenter(startLoc);
    var request = {
      bounds: circle.getBounds(),
      query: document.getElementById('target').value
    };
    initialService.textSearch(request, callback);
  });



  var request = {
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.0, -74.0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.0, -73.0)),
    query: "Starbucks"
  };

  if (noAutoComplete) initialService.textSearch(request, callback);
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.0, -74.0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.0, -73.0)
  );
  if (request && request.bounds) map.fitBounds(request.bounds);
  else map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  if (!noAutoComplete) {
  var input = document.getElementById('target');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  searchBox.setBounds(defaultBounds);
  var markers = [];
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function createMarker(place){
    var placeLoc=place.geometry.location;
    if (place.icon) {
      var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                place.icon, new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                new google.maps.Size(25, 25));
     } else var image = null;

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        icon: image,
        position:place.geometry.location
    });
    var request =  {
          reference: place.reference
    };
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
        service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var contentStr = '<h5>'+place.name+'</h5><p>'+place.formatted_address;
            if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>'+place.formatted_phone_number;
            if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="'+place.website+'">'+place.website+'</a>';
            contentStr += '<br>'+place.types+'</p>';
            infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          } else { 
            var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status="+status+"</h5>";
            infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          }
        });

    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
/*
    if (gmarkers.length==1)
    {
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      map.setZoom(19);
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
    }
*/
    var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers["+parseInt(gmarkers.length-1)+"],\"click\");'>"+place.name+"</a><br>";
    document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += side_bar_html;
}


    </script>
    <style>
      #search-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 100px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="search-panel">
      <input id="target" type="text" placeholder="Starbucks">
    </div>
<table border="1" style="width:800px; height: 500px;"><tr><td style="width:80%;height:100%;">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height: 500px;"></div>
</td><td style="width:300px;height:500px">
    <div id="side_bar"></div>
</td></tr></table>
<div id="info"></div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see the Google Maps library included.

Comment: I put in https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places,geometry   Am I missing something else?

Comment: I meant in your jsfiddle. I can't see the library included there.

Comment: I added it to the resources in the jsfiddle.  I'm not understanding what you mean.

Comment: As far as i know, you need a token to use the maps, I asked about the included library to check if it has any token. You can see more details if you open developer tool and check the console.

Comment: I got it to work by changing the javascript library.  Thanks for helping. https://jsfiddle.net/vibajajo64/shou156m/1/